# Arrange and size multiple plots in Lattice R

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I want to plot three plots vary close together, so they appear as one field. My data are arrays with different dimensions.
Here is some example code to display my problem:

```
library(lattice)

theme.novpadding = list(layout.heights = list(top.padding = 0,
                                          main.key.padding = 0,
                                          key.axis.padding = 0,
                                          axis.xlab.padding = 0,
                                          xlab.key.padding = 0,
                                          key.sub.padding = 0,
                                          bottom.padding = 0),
                    layout.widths =  list(left.padding = 0,
                                          key.ylab.padding = 0,
                                          ylab.axis.padding = 0,
                                          axis.key.padding = 0,
                                          right.padding = 0),
                    axis.line = list(col = "transparent"))


p1 = levelplot(array(c(1:100), c(10,10)), colorkey=F, par.settings=theme.novpadding)
p2 = levelplot(array(c(1:100), c(9,9)), colorkey=F, ylab = NULL, par.settings=theme.novpadding)
p3 = levelplot(array(c(1:100), c(11,11)),  ylab=NULL, par.settings=theme.novpadding)

width = 0.33
height = 1

ph = list(5, "in")

print(p1, position = c(0, 0, width, height), panel.height=ph, more=T)
print(p2, position = c(width, 0, 2*width, height), panel.height=ph, more=T)
print(p3, position = c(2*width, 0, 3*width, height),panel.height=ph, more=F)
```

As you see, they are spread very wide. I want them as close as possible.
I use theme.novpadding to set the margins to zero.
Is the a way to say something like "distance between plots"?

Comment: seems to me that you should make sure the margins of each plot are snug, before arranging them.

Comment: I removed the margins, but unfortunately it didn't change much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trick you could use is to tweak the `position argument`. In stead of not letting the areas overlap, you can do just that to make them close together. For example, you can change the position arguments to:

```
ovr = 0.05
print(p1, position = c(0, 0, width + ovr, height), panel.height=ph, more=T)
print(p2, position = c(width - ovr, 0, 2*width+ovr, height), panel.height=ph, more=T)
print(p3, position = c(2*width - ovr, 0, 3*width, height),panel.height=ph, more=F)
```

You have to some tweaking with this, and I have not tested this code. But I think the general idea should work.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is easy to solve if you structure your data into a nice data.frame. Lattice works best on data.frames. See the example bellow:

```
g.xy <- expand.grid(1:10, 1:10)
my.data <- data.frame(x=g.xy$Var1, y = g.xy$Var2, value1=1:100, value2 = 1:100, value3=1:100, value4=1:100)
levelplot(value1+value2+value3+value4~x+y, data=my.data, scales=list(x="free", y="free")) # free
levelplot(value1+value2+value3+value4~x+y, data=my.data, scales=list(x="same", y="same")) # same range, so panels are "touching"
```

You can control for the plots to appear very close together by setting the scale argument.